# In C# override modifier is mandatory in derive class for virtual/abstract methods of base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

```
public class Shapes
{
  public virtual void Color()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Shapes");
  }
}

public class Square : Shapes
{
  public void Color()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Square");
  }
}

public class Test
{ 
  public static void main()
  {
    Shapes s1 = new Shapes();
    s1.Color();
    Shapes s2 = new Square();
    s2.Color();
  }
}
```

I want to know if the base class has defined some methods virtual, then is it mandatory to override them in derive class? Similarly, If the base class method is abstract, we need to implement the method in derive class, but is override modifier is mandatory? What if override modifier is omitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know if the base class has defined some methods virtual,
>   then is it mandatory to override them in derive class?

Definitely not. It is up to the derived class to decide whether or not to override the virtual method. Note that some classes will *recommend* that derived classes override a particular virtual method in some cases, but the compiler will not enforce that.

> If the base class method is abstract, we need to implement the method
>   in derive class, but is override modifier is mandatory?

Yes, you need to use the `override` keyword, otherwise the method will be hidden by the definition in the derived class.

If you actually run your code, you will see "Shapes" printed twice. That's because the `Color()` method in the `Squares` class isn't declared using the `override` keyword. As such, it *hides* the base class method. This means it will only be accessible through a variable of type `Squares`:

```
Squares s3 = new Squares();
s3.Color();
```

This will print "Square", since you're calling the method on a variable of the correct type.

Comment: Can I say this: You can remember this by conceptually pre-pending the class name, so: 1. Shape.Color() != Square.Color(), so in fact you didn't override Shape.Color(). This solves your second problem. 2. The `virtual` keyword let compiler to find definition **with override keyword** from DerivedClass.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288479%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it may be useful.

A copy in that page:

> To make a method virtual, the **virtual** modifier has to be used in the
>   method declaration of the base class. The derived class can then
>   **override** the base virtual method by using the **override** keyword or hide
>   the virtual method in the base class by using the new keyword. If
>   neither the **override** keyword nor the **new** keyword is specified, the
>   compiler will issue a warning and the method in the derived class will
>   hide the method in the base class

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the example code you posted, the output will be

```
Shapes
Shapes
```

That is because by omitting the `override` keyword you are by default *hiding* the base class method - that means the method cannot be used in a polymorphic fashion anymore - even though `s2` is an instance of `Square` since the object reference used to call the method is `Shapes`, the `Shapes` method is used.

If the method is marked with `override` on the other hand it will be called even on object references of type `Shape` since the most derived `Color()` method in the inheritance tree for the given instance is used.

Answer (score 3):

It is completely based on your logic in first part of your question, In Square class which is derived from Shapes class you declare Color method which will hide its parent virtual Color method, you don't need to duplicate same method in child class when it exists in its parent , except when you want to hide parent class's method. In abstract class if you have a virtual method, you have to implement or override them in derived classes, in you sample those Shapes's instances will invoke virtual Color method in Shapes class.